# How works "set names" query in mysql

Tags: mysql, encoding

I know that query

> SET NAMES utf8

works perfect for synchronization encoding between database and client.
This query sets three database variables in the correct encoding

- character_set_connection
- character_set_results
- character_set_client

But when I set these variables by hand in utf8 value in the database and made "select" query without "SET NAMES utf8" it returned incorrect symbols. 
Somebody can explain why setting variables by hand in the database doesn't work but "set names" query works perfect?

Comment: You also have to consider the client side encoding settings.

Comment: I guess character_set_client variable contains client side encoding.

Comment: The manual says they're identical. Is it possible that your specific client does not fully honour direct changes in `character_set_...` variables?

Comment: I don't know exactly. But I guess client indifferent to the changes these variables in the database. He goes his own way to set. Maybe I wrong.

Comment: You got the meaning of that variable wrong. The server can never change the internal encoding of the client. The client is independent and can do what it wants. The variable only defines what the server assumes as the client encoding. That is a difference. The client have their own configuration and options.